# CCTV camera / PIR security light intereferance

Tags: electrical, security

I have recently installed a CCTV system at home which is working perfectly. The system consists of a KARE® 8CH Digital Video Recorder CCTV Camera System (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00KF55Y42/ref=pe_385721_145294501_TE_3p_dp_1) and two Lorex IP Wireless Camera (http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/lorex-ip-wireless-camera-a75wc). The two wireless cameras are installed either side of my garage door to cover both sides of my motor-home parked on the driveway. The garage is detached from the house with a separate electrical supply including breakers and RCD.

Since the installation of the wireless cameras though the two PIR LED security lights i have covering the driveway have not been working as effectively as they did so before, they are Blooma Bythos 10W Mains Powered PIR Floodlights from B&Q sometimes they come on and stay on, sometimes they don't activate when they should.

The wireless cameras are installed directly above each of the security lights and aimed in the same direction as the lights. Could the cameras be affecting the lights operation, if so how and can this issue be rectified while keeping both lights and cameras in place.

Answer (score 2):

Your LED security lights work on PIR, passive infrared to trigger them on.
The Lorex Camera specs out using
Night Vision
Night Vision Distance   41m
Number of Infra-Red LEDs    24
It is possible the infrared of the cameras are over loading the security lights enough to keep them from working fully.  You can check this simply by turning off the camera or placing a piece of cardboard over the front and see if the lights trigger as expected.
If the two interfere with each other not much can be done other then moving the camera or turning off the night vision ability (kind of defeats the use).
It might be possible to make a small shield to shade the cameras IR from directing into the lights or a directed tube on the lights sensor to narrow the view.
If the interference exists, it is all trial and error to find a placement or shadowing to make it work.  My drive camera had to be raised about ten feet above the leds to make things work as best possible.